# Compilation failed with java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

Probably due to the following bug - https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/613-stack-overflow-exception-while-trying-to-compile Play 2 project failed to compile when route file becomes larger. 
There is the workaround to increase default thread stack size. But this does not work on Heroku. I do not know is it possible to inrease stack size used on Heroku to something that is more than 512k, change of JAVA_OPTS and SBT_OPTS to -Xss2m does not help. 
Compilation failed with exception java.lang.StackOverflowError. 
Maybe anyone can suggest a workaround to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hm, from memory, what does it say when you set `-Xss1m` in JAVA_OPTS and check the settings later using `heroku config`?

Comment: heroku config shows the value I have set that's ok, but maybe this value is not taken into consideration or by some reason it does not solve the issue with StackOverflowError

Answer (score 1):

Ok. The solution is found. 
Stack size should be changed not in config params but in buildpack instead.

To anyone having the same exception on Heroku: just fork buildpack and change line 95 adding    +Xss2m to it